# iText Bookmarks setting font bold and color

Tags: itext

We are generating our bookmarks in a PDF with iText using the following code.

```
private HashMap<String, Object> createBookmark(int pageNumber, String customTitle) {
    HashMap<String, Object> outline = new HashMap<>();
    outline.put("Title", customTitle);
    outline.put("Action", "GoTo");
    outline.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", pageNumber));

    return outline;
}
```

Now I also want to set the font to bold and the color to blue. I know the PdfOutline object has methods to set this, but we aren't using PdfOutline, but this map and the Map works. I have searched on iText website and Google search to find what the Key and Value should be that I add to the map to set these two properties but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out after making about 15 different guesses.

```
HashMap<String, Object> outline = new HashMap<>();
outline.put("Title", "My Book Mark Title");        
outline.put("Action", "GoTo");
outline.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", pageNumber));
outline.put("Color", "0 0 1");
outline.put("Style", "bold");
```

So for color it is RGB values, range is 0-1. So "0 0 1" is full on BLUE!